# Why does: 3.toString() cause the Node.JS REPL to enter a new scope?

Tags: javascript, node.js, read-eval-print-loop

When I enter a literal integer followed by `.toString()` into Node, it enters a new scope by responding with `...`.

### Examples

```
> 3.toString()
...
```

---

```
> 'foo:' + 3.toString()
...
```

---

```
> 'foo:' + 3.toString() + ':bar'
...
```

### Other types seem to work fine

```
> true.toString()
'true'
```

Even this works!

```
> 10.50.toString()
'10.5'
```

### Workaround

Wrapping the literal integer in parenthesis works:

```
> (3).toString()
'3'
```

Is there a reason for this or do you think it's a bug?

Comment: Usually, `3.toString()` is just a syntax error, so I'm not sure why it expects further input…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is because when JavaScript sees a period after an integer, it assumes the value after it will be its decimals. Because of that, simply using `5.toString()` will make JavaScript find `toString` where it expected numbers. If you place it within parentheses, or include decimals yourself, it will work. In fact, this (although it's a bit less clear to read as a human) will work too:

```
5..toString()
```

since an empty decimal point will make JavaScript turn the integer `5` into a float `5`, which would prevent it from assuming there'll be numbers after the next period. That will make JavaScript expect a method after the next period.

What you could also use though is the fact that JavaScript automatically detects the type of the things you're working with. That means you can also simply use this:

```
5+''
```

This will also work when placed mid-string:

```
console.log('We will need '+ 5+5 + 'pizzas.');
//"We will need 55 pizzas."
console.log('We will need '+ (5+5) +' pizzas.');
//"We will need 10 pizzas."
```

Comment: It sure seems better (as in easier to understand what's going on) to use parens than the double period.

Comment: @jfriend00 true, but I put in the `5..toString()` as a demonstration of how this works in JavaScript. That example shows that integers can't have methods placed directly after them, but floats can.

Comment: Very interesting. Great work on identifying the issue so quickly.

Comment: I'm just saying that if you're going to recommend a solution, that recommending the parens around it would be a more readable option.  In this particular case, I don't even know why they're bothering to call `.toString()` as it will be taken care of automatically when adding to another string.

Comment: @jfriend00 read the extra bit at the bottom about `5+''`. That is the solution I myself use all the time.

Comment: @jfriend00 No, I wanted to know *why* it was happening, not the workaround because I already had a workaround.

Comment: @wizlb - answers are SO aren't just for you the OP, they're for all the other readers too which is why I commented.  Anyway, the requisite info is in the answer now.

Comment: @jfriend00 Ahh, well the *original* question is still "Is there a reason for this or do you think it's a bug?". If you want to change my question to "What is the best way to work around this particular behvior?" then I'd agree with you.

Comment: @wizlb - the best answers on SO teach far beyond what was originally asked about.  Excuuuuuse me for suggesting ways the answerer could improve their answer for other readers (NOT for you).  People who write answers should not get bothered when people make suggestions for things they could add to improve their answer.  That's how SO is supposed to work.  And, its even more bizarre for people who ask questions to object to comments asking for more info to be included in an answer.  Simply bizarre.

Comment: This is looking like it might escalate, so let's not have that happen guys. I added extra bits to my answer which made it also have a suggestion based on my own experience, and it explains what's happening in the JS engine. Everybody's happy. PS: @wizlb, could you please mark this answer as accepted?